# EXTJS - remove option to select columns

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

how can I remove the option to select the columns on my extjs grid:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try setting property `enableColumnHide:false`

refer : [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-enableColumnHide)

Answer (score 4):

You can also set this as a property when configuring each of the columns. Just set `hideable: false` for each of them.

The [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-columns) tells you all the configs, be here's an example of a few that might be handy:

```
columns: [
    {
        header:'MyHeader',
        dataIndex: 'myData',
        menuDisabled: true,
        draggable: true,
        sortable: true,
        resizeable: true,
        hideable: false,
        hidden: false
    }
]
```